# Having issue extracting java data from NASA website

Tags: java, web-scraping

http://disc2.nascom.nasa.gov/Giovanni/tovas/realtime.3B42RT.2.shtml

I am working on a project and trying to extract this data for a project on rainfall throughout the world.

Experimental Real-Time TRMM Multi-Satellite Precipitation Analysis (TMPA-RT): 3B42RT

I cannot figure out how to view and manipulate this data, java or non-java version.  I also do not have experience w/ Java.

Any tips or ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: So are you trying to build a java app without java experience? I don't get it. How?

Comment: What programming languages _do_ you know? Try one of those rather than try to climb two hills at once.

Comment: I know only ruby.  I am trying to just simply view this data in anyway possible, not necessarily build an app.